# Unable to deserialize Object Array via Jackson Yaml

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am attempting to deserialize a YAML configuration file which maps a particular action (enum) to arguments (String[]).  In order to have a starting point for the YAML, I first built the object structure in Java and then serialized it.

Reading that output back in and deserializing it also results in the exception below which is unexpected because that is straight from the horse's mouth.

My Java structure:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Data
public class Session {
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude protected List<ActionInstance> actions;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Data
public class ActionInstance {
  protected Action action;
  protected String[] arguments;
}

public enum Action {
  Left,
  Right,
  Up,
  Down;
}
```

YAML (this is taken directly from the serialized output from Jackson, reading it back causes the exception below):

```
actions: !<java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12>
- !<java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12>
  arguments:
  - 90.00
  action: Left
```

Jackson Service to deserialize:

```
objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Session.class)
```

Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
Unexpected token (VALUE_STRING), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class Action
```

EDIT #1:

```
final Session export = new Session();
        export.setActions(
            List.of(
                new ActionInstance(Action.Left, new String[] {"90.00"})));
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        serializationService.serialize(export, baos);
```

The Jackson implementation I have is roughly this:

```
outputStream.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data));
```

ObjectMapperProvider:

```
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements Provider<ObjectMapper> {
  protected final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
  protected final JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();

  @Inject
  public ObjectMapperProvider() {
    // Hack time module to allow 'Z' at the end of string (i.e. javascript json's)
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(
        LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator());
```

Comment: In the second line, `!<java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12>` is wrong since an `ActionInstance` object is expected. More importantly, Jackson is a high-level abstraction and therefore should never generate YAML tags (as that is not a JSON feature) so the question arises what you're doing to get this output. Please show the code generating this YAML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple:

actions: !<java.util.ArrayList>

- arguments:

  - 90.00
    action: !<com.walterjwhite.stackoverflow.Action> Left